# Create an error text file in Applescript

Tags: error-handling, applescript

Here's a script that renames a group of files to their new filenames created in excel. It works and it's great! But the problem is if the files do not exist from the group of files the scripts ends and creates an error..

```
property sourceFolder : "Macintosh HD:Users:COMP1:Desktop:folder1" -- adjust as appropriate 

set filenameList to read file "Macintosh HD:Users:COMP1:Desktop:renamethis.txt" using delimiter {return}

set {oldDelims, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, tab}


tell application "Finder"
    repeat with aFile in filenameList
        set codified_name to (sourceFolder & ":" & (text item 1 of aFile)) as string
        set real_name to text item 2 of aFile
        set name of file codified_name to real_name
    end repeat
end tell
```

I asked around for some help and they gave me this code to add. The problem is I do not know how and where to add this code and how to define it. I want to be able to create a .txt file that contain the files not renamed instead of stopping the whole script.

```
try
   set name of file codified_name to real_name
on error error_string number error_number
   write error_string to log_file_handle starting at eof
end
```

I don't really know how to code and just rely on posts from the internet and try to tweak them. So if anyone can help me..that would be really really awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Here, this shows how to add a try block into your code above. You needed more code to write to an error log file as well. Should be enough to go on:

```
property sourceFolder : "Macintosh HD:Users:COMP1:Desktop:folder1" -- adjust as appropriate 
set log_file_path to "Macintosh HD:Users:COMP1:Desktop:myErrorLogFile.txt"
set {oldDelims, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, tab}
try
    set filenameList to read file "Macintosh HD:Users:COMP1:Desktop:renamethis.txt" using delimiter {return}
    tell application "Finder"
        repeat with aFile in filenameList
            set codified_name to (sourceFolder & ":" & (text item 1 of aFile)) as string
            set real_name to text item 2 of aFile
            set name of file codified_name to real_name
        end repeat
    end tell
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
on error error_string number error_number
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
    set log_file_handle to (open for access file log_file_path with write permission)
    write ((current date) as string) & tab & error_string to log_file_handle starting at eof
    close access log_file_handle
end try
```

Comment: Oh my god! It works! I just had to add "with write permission" for the open for access because it gave me error -61 at first. Thank you so much @jweaks! I'm buying a book about this Applescript thing. It's awesome!

Comment: Glad it works. I added the clause, which was a typo really to leave out in the first place. Sorry. Please 'accept' the answer if it satisfies so the topic is marked as answered.